# Custom Button to Update Child Records

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Can someone point me to a code sample that does the following:

**I want to update a custom field on all the account related contact records called relationship__c from a button on the parent account record.**

I do not care if the button is a detail or list button. All it needs to do is get the account ID, search for all the child contact records and update that field to say relationship__C = "New". That's it but for someone who is not familiar with javascript, I'm hitting a wall. (I can update the account record but can't seem to get the contacts.) If anyone can help with a code example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far to your question, it'll help others point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke an apex class using the AJAX Toolkit. Here is one small example.

Create a custom button on Account and select JavaScript Execute onclick:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")} 
var id= '{!Account.Id}'; 
alert(id); 
sforce.apex.execute('buttoncls','updateRecord',{recId :id}); 

window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Create an Apex webservive class and write your logic. Here is the code:

```
global class buttoncls {
    webservice static void updateRecord(Id recId){

        System.debug('------Method called on button click.....');
        list<contact> con  = new list<contact>();

        if(recId!=null)
        {
            for (Contact c :[select id ,phone from Contact where accountid=:recId])
            {
                c.phone='123';
                con.add(c);
            }

             update con;
        }
    } 
}
```

Add your button from page layouts...

**Cheers**
**Vineeth**

Comment: HI @KarolF ,Could be please close this question marking these as best answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can actually do this without resorting to the use of JavaScript. I used the following blog post by our very own [Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) to use as a reference and create a List Button based on your example.

**I have not had a chance to completely test it, but I am fairly confident this will work.**

Using this information I can create the following controller:

```
public with sharing class CreateNewRelationshipListController
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController AccountSetController;

    public CreateNewRelationshipListController(ApexPages.StandardSetController inheritedSetController)
    {
        AccountSetController = inheritedSetController;
    }

    public PageReference SetContactRelationshipsToNew()
    {
        List<Account> selectedAccounts = (List<Account>)AccountSetController.getSelected();

        if(selectedAccounts.size() > 0)
        {
            Set<Id> accountIdSet = (new Map<Id, Account>(selectedAccounts)).keyset();

            List<Contact> contactsToUpdateRelationships = [SELECT Id, Relationship__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdSet];


            if(contactsToUpdateRelationships.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Contact contactToUpdateRelationship : contactsToUpdateRelationships)
                    contactToUpdateRelationship.Relationship__c = 'New';

                UPDATE contactsToUpdateRelationships;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Next you would have to create a custom VisualForce page to specify the action once your user clicks the custom button:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CreateNewRelationshipListController"
           action="{!SetContactRelationshipsToNew}" recordSetVar="accountsToProcess">
```

Lastly, you would create a custom list button, choose display checkboxes (so you can select multiple Accounts), and choose the VisualForce created above as the Content Source.

There **are** reservations to this. Mainly this is open CSRF attacks. So you should be weary of that.

For more information on how to accomplish this, please take a look at this [blog post I used as a reference](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/) for more information.

There is actually another link that the blog mentions, where you can use the same controller for either a List Button **and** Detail Page Button. You can find more information [here](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/using-one-page-and-controller-for-both-a-detail-page-button-and-a-list-button/), but it's not the most elegant solution (which the author admits himself).